# child_process spawnSync iterate python stdout results using for loop

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

First I will post my code,

I will give an example of what I am facing problem:

```
        for(var i=0;i<arrayleng.length;i++){
        var oneScript = spawnSync('python',["/home/demo/mypython.py",arrayleng[i].path]);
        //console.log(String(oneScript.stdout));

        fs.readFile('/home/demo/' + arrayleng[i].filename + '.json','utf8',function(err,data){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })          
    };
```

I want spawn child to synchronous only because, my python scripts will return some files, it has to read after each time it executes python script. But now it is reading once after it completes execution of python.And printing it on console at once.Instead of printing after each time it executes python script.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure your loop body ends where you think it does? Is this your complete, actual code?

Comment: Hi thank you very much for reply. I have edited my question. can you please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe your second `spawnSync` call throws an exception? Or `arrayleng.length` is only `1`?

Comment: Also maybe try iterating `oneScript.output` what does the python script `print` or `write` to stdout? Can you include the python script as well?

Comment: Also this might help to see what gets executed when: https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Comment: hi @bergi, thanks for reply. No exceptions. And arrayleng.length is not 1 it can be 5,10 or 100, its a dynamic value. And I want just fs.readFile to read a file as soon as spawnSync executes a file. the code is there in the for loop. But spawnSync s blocking event.  can you please help me.

Comment: So is your actual problem that it logs only once (despite the loop reading multiple files), or that it logs too late (after the blocking loop)?

Comment: Also your question is quite unclear with the two snippets doing very different things - one use `readFileSync` the other `spawnSync`, one logs synchronously inside the loop the other logs from an asynchronous callback. Which is the one that you are actually using, and what problems do you have with it? Can you remove the other if it has nothing to do with those problems?

Comment: Hi @bergi, I have edited my question.  the code logs multiple times , I mean depends upon **arrayleng.length**, suppose length is 10 , I am getting 10 logs. But the control is not executing next line that is fs.readFile every time in the loop. it only executes  after python scripts executes to **arrayleng.length** then the control is moving to next line. I want both spawnSync and fs.readFile to execute one after the other till **arrayleng.length**.

Comment: Because python script will give file as output, that file has to read by fs.readFile. Both should be synchronous.

Comment: Well, then use `spawnSync` and `readFileSync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nodejs example:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var checkThese = ['/Users/jmunsch/Desktop/code_scraps/1.json', '/Users/jmunsch/Desktop/code_scraps/2.json']

checkThese.forEach(function(checkThisPath){
    // Both of these will log first
    console.log(`run first: ${checkThisPath}`)
    var data = fs.readFileSync(checkThisPath, 'utf8')
    var theJson = data
    console.log(`run first: ${theJson}`)

    // it might make sense that this would execute next
    // but it doesn't
    fs.readFile(checkThisPath, 'utf8', function(err, data){
        // this callback executes later
        console.log(`run second: ${checkThisPath}`)
        console.log(`run second: ${data}`)
    })
})
```

Here is an example of a python script and a nodejs script and how they might work.

The python script `listdir.py`:

```
import os
import sys
for x in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
    print(x)
```

Notes on the above script, I used `print` which appends a `\n` character after each line. If you plan to `write` a file to `stdout` using python's `sys.stdout.write` it will not add a newline character.

The nodejs code:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var spawnSync = child_process.spawnSync

var checkThese = ['/Users', '/Users/jmunsch']

for (var i=0; i < checkThese.length;i++){
    var checkThisPath = checkThese[i]
    console.log(`Checking: ${checkThisPath}`)
    var oneScript = spawnSync('python',["listdir.py", checkThisPath]);
    oneScript.output.forEach(function(buffer){
        if (buffer){
            // convert to string
            var x = buffer.toString('utf8')
            console.log(`typeof x: ${typeof x}`)
            // split by new line character
            var y = x.split('\n')
            console.log(`typeof y: ${typeof y}`)
            // turn it into an array
            var z = Array.prototype.slice.call(y)
            // iterate each line in the array
            z.forEach(function(pythonOutput){
                console.log(`One python print(): ${pythonOutput}`)
            })
        }
    })    
}
```

The output from from the nodejs code:

```
Checking: /Users
typeof x: string
typeof y: object
One python print(): .localized
One python print(): administrator
One python print(): casperadministrator
One python print(): jmunsch
One python print(): Shared
One python print(): 
typeof x: string
typeof y: object
One python print(): 
Checking: /Users/jmunsch
typeof x: string
typeof y: object
One python print(): .account
One python print(): .ansible
One python print(): .bash_sessions
One python print(): .cache
One python print(): .CFUserTextEncoding
One python print(): .config
One python print(): .cups
One python print(): .DS_Store
One python print(): .eclipse
One python print(): .gitconfig
One python print(): .ipython
One python print(): .lesshst
One python print(): .lldb
One python print(): .local
One python print(): .m2
One python print(): .netrc
One python print(): .node-gyp
One python print(): .node_repl_history
One python print(): .npm
One python print(): .nvm
One python print(): .oh-my-zsh
One python print(): .oracle_jre_usage
One python print(): .p2
One python print(): .profile
One python print(): .putty
One python print(): .python-eggs
One python print(): .rediscli_history
One python print(): .RSA
One python print(): .sh_history
One python print(): .ssh
One python print(): .swift
One python print(): .tooling
One python print(): .Trash
One python print(): .vagrant.d
One python print(): .viminfo
One python print(): .wget-hsts
One python print(): .zcompdump-LM-SFA-11003286-5.0.8
One python print(): .zsh-update
One python print(): .zsh_history
One python print(): .zshrc
One python print(): Applications
One python print(): Desktop
One python print(): Documents
One python print(): Downloads
One python print(): eclipse
One python print(): git
One python print(): Library
One python print(): Movies
One python print(): Music
One python print(): Pictures
One python print(): Public
One python print(): synced
One python print(): THEBIGPIN
One python print(): VirtualBox VMs
One python print(): 
typeof x: string
typeof y: object
One python print():
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for reply. I have edited my question. can you please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Hi jmunsch. Thank u very much for the code. I can print what my python script will execute. But the control is not executing fs.readFile (next line) until spawnSync completely executes python script with all the files loaded. For example if  **arrayleng.length** is 10 , it will halt in the **spawnSync** line only, after 10th file gets executed it will start with fs.readFile. Can you please help me. As soon as it executes one python script it has to go to next line. I dono why for loop is not working

Comment: @naik3 I do not understand what you mean when you say "it will halt in spawnSync" the nodejs code will block or wait until spawnSync finishes?At which point you would have access to the results/output/stdout. Can you update your question and include the python script? Also of use might be to include some "Psuedo Code" describing what exactly you would like the process to do. How many python scripts are there? What do the python scripts look like? What do you mean goto next line after python scripts?

Comment: Hi @jmunsch , can you please help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622647/how-to-make-spawnsync-and-fs-readfile-to-execute-one-after-other)

Comment: @naik3 ping me in the stackoverflow python chat, err, maybe the nodejs chat?