# How to make spawnSync and fs.readFile to execute one after other?

Tags: javascript, python, json, node.js, express

I have a python script which returns a `JSON` file as output by taking a FILE as input.

I have 10 files, I am using **spawnSync** inside **for loop** and inside loop I have **fs.readFile** for reading JSON file which is coming from the python script.

But the problem is **spawnSync** is blocking **fs.readFile** until it executes python scripts with all 10 files. Since both **spawnSync** and **fs.readFile** are inside **for loop**, I want **fs.readFile** to read a JSON file as soon as first python script executes and outputs JSON file.

But it is not happening. **spawnSync** is blocking and it is continuing with next file to execute python script.**fs.reafFile** should prints data as soon as the file gets executes. please help, Here is my code snippet.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawnSync;
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = ['first.txt','second.txt','third.txt',....]
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  var myscript = spawn('python',['/pathToPython/myPython.py',filename[i]]);
  fs.readFile('/pathToPython/' + filename[i] + '.json','utf8',function(err,data){
         if(err){
               console.log(err);
         }else{
               console.log(data);
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: readFile is asynchronous so using sync version readFileSync should help.

Comment: Hi @Molda, thanks for reply, still not woking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are rely to use third party module then I recommend to use [async.eachSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachSeries) the method of the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module to resolve this issue

```
var filename = ['first.txt','second.txt','third.txt',....]
async.eachSeries(filename, function(item, next) {

  var myscript = spawn('python', ['/pathToPython/myPython.py', item]);
  fs.readFile('/pathToPython/' + item + '.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      next();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi @abdulbarik, thanks for reply. can you please help me in understanding code ** sourceData**??

Comment: `eachSeries`  iterates with the `callback next` mean next iteration will not be run until the callback call. so here after your complete execution of python script and readFile the `next` callback call and move for next iteration

Comment: Thank you. In my case what i have to type  `sourceData ` here.

Comment: It's an array type

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will implement in my code.  I am using `spawnSync` do i need to change it to asynchronous  only `spawn` .

Comment: You can, but it'll not impact on this flow since it iterate one by one due to `aync.eachSeries`

Comment: Ok. Last question. In the line `fs.readFile('/pathToPython/' + item + '.json', 'utf8', function(err, data)` , you have changed from `filename[i]` to `item`. Will the `item` contains filename??

Comment: yes, of course, did you run that code? and you can check it

Comment: I missed to add item in python script now I updated answer

Comment: Glad to help you !!

Comment: HI @abdulbarik, I tried what you explained, it is working fine. I am facing a another problem, As soon as python script write a JSON file, in the same cycle `fs.readFile` is trying to read file. And i am ending up in error, saying that file does't exist. Is there any way that i can induce delay before `fs.readFile`

Comment: You can see async.waterfall, write python script in first function and  readfile in final callback